# Unique value combination in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm building a simple friendship table with 3 columns: id, user1, user2

Once a user becomes friends with another user, their ids will be added to the table like this:

```
+----+-------+-------+
| id | user1 | user2 |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 |   15  |   9   |
+----+-------+-------+
|  2 |   9   |   32  |
+----+-------+-------+
```

The above table is ok but in some cases, a user might want to become friends with a user they are already friends with, resulting in the following table:

```
+----+-------+-------+
| id | user1 | user2 |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 |   15  |   9   |
+----+-------+-------+
|  2 |   9   |   32  |
+----+-------+-------+
|  3 |   9   |   15  |
+----+-------+-------+
```

In this table, index 1 and 3 are in conflict with each other (2 & 3 are NOT) and I would therefore like an error returned upon insertion (duplicate entry). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When inserting into this table, before you issue the query, you should always make sure that `user1` has the smaller of the two user IDs. Then the situation you described will never happen.

You can implement this either in your application code, or as a stored procedure that you execute to insert a new relation between two users.

Comment: By stored procedure you mean "before insert" trigger, just to be more specific?

Comment: @Bulat no, stored procedures are not triggers. What I meant was that instead of forming a query in the application code, the query can be executed by a stored procedure.

Comment: Ok. Before insert would be an alternative option then.

Comment: @Bulat yes, that is another possibility. Although I believe that implementing this as a trigger obscures the logic a little bit, from the standpoint of maintaining the code.

Comment: I guess the trigger vs app code decision is a matter of team's taste. I don't see why it would obscure anything compared to stored procedure.

Answer (score 3):

Let me offer another perspective.  You might want to keep the friends table as a reciprocal relationship.  So, *both* directions would be stored in the table.  The correct table would look like:

```
----+-------+-------+
| id | user1 | user2 |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 |   15  |   9   |
+----+-------+-------+
|  2 |   9   |   15  |
+----+-------+-------+
|  3 |   9   |   32  |
+----+-------+-------+
|  4 |   32  |   9   |
+----+-------+-------+
```

Why would you want to do just an absurd thing, doubling the size of the data?  Typical queries on such data are about who is a friend of friend or to list all the friends of a given user.  Such queries require traversing this data as a graph structure, and you need both links.  Not only do such queries become much more complicated with a single row per friendship, but because subqueries (derived tables) are often involved, the query loses the ability to use indexes.

With this structure, you need to be careful when inserting to insert both directions of the relationship.  Then a simple `unique` constraint on the two columns ensures that duplicates are not inserted.

Comment: That's a good point. Another perspective I can think of is that user1 adding user2 as a friend doesn't mean they are friends until user2 also adds user1. And it is quite likely that the application should logically differentiate between these two actions/relationships.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a trigger to automatically fix this, similar to Dmytro's answer:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgr_uid_check BEFORE INSERT ON Relationships 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
      IF NEW.user1 > NEW.user2 THEN 
        SET @user1 = NEW.user1;
        SET NEW.user1 = NEW.user2;
        SET NEW.user2 = @user1;
      END IF; 
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a simple query to check if there is already a friendship:

```
SELECT id
FROM your_table
WHERE (user1 = numToInsert1 AND user2 = numToInsert2) 
OR (user1 = numToInsert2 AND user2 = numToInsert1)
```

If this statement returns anything it means that there is already a friendship between those two. If this statement does not return anything insert your new friendship.